# Bootstrap approach for testing differences in interquartile range suitable?

Tags: confidence-interval, t-test, bootstrap

I am investigating differences in two groups of forecast errors (absolute values / unsigned) that both have a strongly right-skewed distributions. Both groups of errors have the same number of observations (about 4000). As I like to test if the interquartile range and the fraction of errors that are <0.4 differ significantly from each other, I like to implement a significance test (and attach confidence limits).

Actually this is what I have considered as an appropriate approach:
I like to generate samples of about 5000 observations by drawing observations randomly from the constructed sample (about 5000 obs.) with replacement. For each trial, I will compute the IQR and the fraction of errors <0.4, and then compute the difference of such measure across different valuation methods. This process shall be repeated 100 (ore more) times and a distribution for the difference of IQR (<0.4) shall be obtained. A t-statistic could be computed as the mean divided by the standard deviation of this distribution.

Would you regard this approach as appropriate for a heavily right-skewed distribution considering my aims? How would I implement that using R as I will not bootstrap the differences but the errors of the two groups (e.g., A and B)?

Comment: I have edited the question in order to make sure that this question  is of interest for the community.

Comment: You did a good job re-shaping the original question to meet the goals and interests of this site: thank you!

Comment: Is anyone willing to help on this issue?

Comment: There are some issues with using the median with the bootstrap (most notably with small samples), and those issues will extend to the quartiles. [You don't have an issue with small samples, but the use of the smooth bootstrap (which often helps in small samples) might be considered even for larger samples.]